# How can I get rid of extra vertical spacing in table cell?

Tags: html, css

In this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vGAm6/

```
<table style="width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr class="top-padding" style="height: 64px; width: 100%;"></tr>
    <tr class="content" style="width: 100%;">
      <td class="content-container" style="padding: 0;">
        <table class="content" style="width: 600px; margin: auto; border-collapse: collapse;">
          <tr class="header" style="background-color: black;">
            <td style="padding: 0; width: 96px;"><img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/0j0j1K3m2I413t3U1533/1389661583_bird_twitter_new_square.png" style="width:64px; height: 64px;"/></td>
            <td style="padding: 0; color: white; font-weight: lighter; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 32px;">Cool Beans</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

There is an obtrusive `4px` padding below the image.  How can I make it go away?

Comment: Try `img { display: block; }` or add `style="display: block;"` to your `img` tag, `img` tags render `inline` by default, browsers render extra spacing under `inline` elements to allow for descenders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the vertical alignment on the image:

```
img {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vGAm6/2/)**